# Type 'Double' has no member 'random'

Tags: ios, swift, random, double

I am  fairly new to IOS development, I am trying to use the swift [double.random(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2995409-random).

this is the example from the documentation:

```
for _ in 1...3 {
    print(Double.random(in: 10.0 ..< 20.0))
}
// Prints "18.1900709259179"
// Prints "14.2286325689993"
// Prints "13.1485686260762"
```

Here is my code, I am trying to generate random colors:

```
UIColor(red: Double.random(in: 1.0 ..< 251.0),
        green: Double.random(in: 1.0 ..< 251.0),
        blue: Double.random(in: 1.0 ..< 251.0),
        aplha: 1);
```

But I keep getting the Error

> **Type 'Double' has no member 'random'**

Comment: You should use CGFloat and it should be between 0 and 1. Btw Swift is a type inferred language. You can just omit the type.

Comment: `UIColor(red: .random(in: 0 ..< 1),
        green: .random(in: 0 ..< 1),
        blue: .random(in: 0 ..< 1),
        alpha: 1)`

Comment: I am using Xcode 9.

Comment: For a solid color you can use UIColor hue saturation and brightness initializer and pass `UIColor(hue: .random(in: 0 ..< 1),
        saturation: 1,
        brightness: 1,
        alpha: 1)`

Comment: If Xcode 9, you can’t use this pattern introduce in Xcode 10.

Comment: @TiisetsoTjabane just update your app in the AppStore. Xcode 10.2 (Swift5) was released 4 days ago

Comment: @Leo this had me going crazy, I ll update

Thanks

Comment: For now you can also use arc4random_uniform `UIColor(hue: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255,
        saturation: 1,
        brightness: 1,
        alpha: 1)`

Comment: Your answer is exactly what OP is trying to achieve. IMO using the HSB initializer gives you much more control  on the resulting colors. As I said "For a solid color you can use UIColor..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Xcode 9, you can’t use [`.random(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2995409-random) which was introduce in Xcode 10. Instead use `arc4random_uniform`:

```
let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(250) + 1) / 255, 
                    green: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(250) + 1) / 255,
                    blue: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(250) + 1) / 255, 
                    alpha: 1)
```

I’m not sure why you’re going from 1 to 251 (which I obviously assumed you wanted to divide by 255, because the range of values in 8 bit channels is 0...255. When using `arc4random_uniform`, you achieve that by supplying a parameter value of 256:

```
let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255, 
                    green: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255,
                    blue: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255, 
                    alpha: 1)
```

---

Note the use of `CGFloat`, above. As a rule, UIKit uses `CGFloat`, not `Double`. So, if you were using Xcode 10, you could do:

```
let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1),
                    green: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1),
                    blue: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1),
                    alpha: 1)
```

Or you can just take advantage of the fact that Swift knows the type of these parameters, and let it infer the `CGFloat`:

```
let color = UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1),
                    green: .random(in: 0...1),
                    blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                    alpha: 1)
```

Comment: thank you, I have learnt a lot from your answer.  255 is the right number for RGB color system, I have updated to use your first answer and is working like a charm.